# Patterns for Showing a Toast Popup with Custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, swift3, cocoa-design-patterns

Currently, I have a `CustomTableViewCell` that is used in four or 5 different places. The custom cell has a lazy loaded `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` property that gets added as a gesture recognizer in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in the parent VC.

```
self.tableView.addGestureRecognizer(cell.longPress)
```

When a user initiates the long press, I want a toast notification to popup displaying some contextual information, and then to disappear after a few seconds. I've included this in my code for the `CustomTableViewCell`, but all of these decisions are starting to "smell." Is there a smarter, more logical way to be implementing these decisions?

This table view cell has the following code:

```
weak var parentTableView: UITableView?

lazy var longPress: UILongPressGestureRecognizer = {

    let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPressSelector))

    longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.5
    longPress.delegate = self

    return longPress

}()

func longPressSelector(_ longPress: UILongPressGestureRecognizer!) {

    if let tableView = self.parentTableView {

        let point = longPress.location(in: tableView)

        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: point)

        if ((indexPath! as NSIndexPath).section == 0 && longPress.state == .began) {


            // do some work

            // Show informational popup
            let toast = createToastNotification(withTitle: addedSong.name)

            Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2.0, repeats: false) { (timer) -> Void in
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) { () -> Void in
                    toast.alpha = 0.0
                    toast = nil
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

func createToastNotification(withTitle title: String) -> UIView {

    if let tableView = self.parentTableView {
        let windowFrame = tableView.superview?.bounds

        let height:CGFloat = 145, width: CGFloat = 145

        let x = (windowFrame?.width)! / 2 - width / 2
        let y = (windowFrame?.height)! / 2 - height / 2

        let toast = EnsembleToastView.create()

        toast.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
        toast.songLabel.text = title
        toast.layer.cornerRadius = 5

        tableView.superview?.addSubview(toast)

        return toast
    }

    return UIView()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it makes more sense for the TableView to know how to display a toast so I would create a protocol in your tableViewCell, so I would take the following steps.

- Make the TableViewController responsible for:

  - creating toast (only once)
  - configuring toast
  - showing toast
  - responding to long press gesture
  - configuring your table view cell
- Allow YourTableViewCell to only delegate

---

So let's do **responding to long press gesture** first

```
protocol TableViewCellLongPressDelegate {
    func tableViewCellHadLongPress(_ cell: YourTableViewCell)
}
```

Then extend your TableViewController to conform to your new protocol

```
extension YourTableViewController : TableViewCellLongPressDelegate {
    func tableViewCellHadLongPress(_ cell: YourTableViewCell){
         //configure toast based on which cell long pressed
         configureToastNotification(with title: cell.title){
         //show toast
    }
}
```

---

Now, **configuring your table view cell**  within your TableViewController configure your cell and assign the TableViewController as the longPressDelegate

```
let cell = YourTableViewCell.dequeue(from: self.tableView)!
//configure cell
cell.tableViewCellLongPressDelegate = self
```

---

This approach is nice because you can move the createToastNotification() method to your TableViewController and **be responsible for creating toast (only once)**

```
var toastNotification : UIView?
viewDidLoad(){
    //yatta yatta
    toastNotification = createToastNotification()
}
```

Then you can change createToastNotification to

```
func createToastNotification() -> UIView? {

    let windowFrame = self.bounds

    let height:CGFloat = 145, width: CGFloat = 145

    let x = (windowFrame?.width)! / 2 - width / 2
    let y = (windowFrame?.height)! / 2 - height / 2

    let toast = EnsembleToastView.create()

    toast.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
    toast.layer.cornerRadius = 5

   self.addSubview(toast)

    return toast
}
```

---

Lastly for YourTableViewController, **configuring toast**, let's create a configureToastNotification(with title: String) like:

```
func configureToastNotification(with title: String){
    if let toast = self.toastNotification {
        toast.songLabel.text = title
    }
}
```

---

For the end, we remove a lot of the responsibility from YourTableViewCell and **allow it to only delegate** :

```
protocol TableViewCellLongPressDelegate : class {
    func tableViewCellHadLongPress(_ cell: YourTableViewCell)
}

class YourTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {

    //initializers

    weak var longPressDelegate: TableViewCellLongPressDelegate?

    lazy var longPress: UILongPressGestureRecognizer = {

        let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPressHappened))

        longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.5
        longPress.delegate = self

        return longPress

    }()

    func longPressHappened() {
        self.longPressDelegate?.tableViewCellHadLongPress(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: This was perfect. I'd already started working in the delegate direction, and your edit that included the new selector on the CustomTableViewCell put it over the top. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @dstepan Glad I could help.